# Launcher IOS app

Tags: ios, mobile, safari, app-store

Can I submit to App Store an app that only launch Safari with one specific url?
If the answer is "yes": Can I hide default image, that is, can I launch Safari inmediatly from Main without show deafault image? (I can do it in BlackBerry and Windows Mobile)
I know.. is a horrible app but is what I have to do..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See section 2.12 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> Apps that are not very useful, are
>   simply web sites bundled as apps, or
>   do not provide any lasting
>   entertainment value may be rejected

And section 12.3:

> Apps that are simply web clippings,
>   content aggregators, or a collection
>   of links, may be rejected

In short, the answer is: Yes, you can submit whatever you like. My guess based on the guidelines above, though, is that such an app is unlikely to pass the review process.